# bottom navigation view + Fab Action bar

Tags: android, kotlin

Necesito consejo o ayuda con lo siguiente.
Estoy haciendo una app en la que tengo una MainActivity con un BottonNavigation (El que crea por defecto el android Studio) con tres fragments distintos para cada pestaña de la navegación.

El tema es que en uno de ellos (uno de esos fragments) tengo un ReciclerView y un FabActionBar en el. Bien, el tema es que quiero que en ese botón del fab al pulsarlo cargue otro fragment para la inserción de datos.

¿Como puedo hacer esto?

Gracias de antemano!
Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El codigo que quieres quedaria tal que asi , solo modificalo a tu gusto.

```
 FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(ruta_origen.this, ruta_destino.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
    });
```

Espero que resuelva tu duda.

**Edicion 1**

Segun la documentacion de android:
(Ignora la parte de animacion si no te interesa)

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

Recuerda tener presente el nombre de la clase de tu fragmento. En este caso se llama GastosFragmentNuevo.

Después, en el lugar en donde vas hacer la transacción pon el siguiente código:

```
// Crear fragmento de tu clase
Fragment fragment = new GastosFragmentNuevo();
// Obtener el administrador de fragmentos a través de la actividad
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
// Definir una transacción
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
// Remplazar el contenido principal por el fragmento
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_principal, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
// Cambiar
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Gracias @Shockz por la respuesta. Pero tengo entendido que Intent es para Actividades,no? Un saludo.

Comment: tienes razon , no me fije en lo de fragment, dejame contestarte mejor

Comment: Gracias @Shockz. Al final hize lo que quería con actividades... Probé lo que me comentaste y funciona muy bien. El único problema es que visualmente no me gustaba mucho y me tiré a las actividades. Gracias!!!